# play pause multiple vimeo videos in Bootstrap modals

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, vimeo, froogaloop

I'm trying to get more than one Vimeo video to play and pause using the Bootstrap modal. I can get it working for one video on the page, but not multiple videos in separate modals.

I used the code from an earlier post on here and it works well for one video.
[Play and stop Vimeo video placed in Bootstrap modal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24952984/play-and-stop-vimeo-video-placed-in-bootstrap-modal/29170390#29170390)

Does anyone know how to get multiple videos working? I have tried to use 2 seperate video ids as variables but I don't think this is the right thing to do and it didn't work.

This is what I have working so far - http://jsbin.com/foveqi/1/edit?html,css,js,output

Answer (score 0):

You do need to use separate id's for the videos. Then you can use a little jQuery along with the Bootstrap toggle button to control the videos. The important part is setting up event listeners...

```
    player.addEvent('ready', function() {
          player.addEvent('pause', onPause);
          player.addEvent('finish', onFinish);
          player.addEvent('playProgress', onPlayProgress);
   });
```

Demo: http://codeply.com/go/JnIJLgXjyt

Comment: You're demo doesn't seem to work, can you go in to a little more detail on how to get the event listeners to work?

Comment: Nothing happens when I click the play buttons.

Comment: Firefox, but I've just tried it in Chrome and it does work there. However do you know how to add the event listeners to stop/pause video when a modal is closed, and to play a new video in a different modal if another link is clicked?

Comment: That's almost what I'm looking for. I've tried to take what you have done a repurpose it slightly, but it's breaking for me. Rather than have the .text change the message on the button to say play or pause, the play button would be div and the pause button would just be a close 'X' button. When I try removing .text the video doesn't stop on modal close.